# Mapping JPA entity relationships

Tags: jpa

I would like some advice on how to best layout my JPA entity classes. Suppose I have 2 tables I would like to model as entities, user and role.

```
Create Table users(user_id primary key,
                   role_id integer not null )
Create table role(role_id primary key,
                  description text,
                  )
```

I create the following two JPA Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class User implements Serializable {
      private Long userId;
      private Long roleId;
      private Role role;

      @Column(name = "user_id")
      @Id
      public Long getUserId() {}

     @Column(name = "role_id")
      public Long getRoleId() {}

      @ManyToOne()
      JoinColumn(name="role_id")
      public Role getRole() {}
}
```

Role Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Role")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Role implements Serializable {
      private String description;
      private Long roleId;


      @Column(name = "role_id")
      @Id
      public Long getRoleId() {}

     @Column(name = "description")
      public Long getDescrition(){}

      @ManyToOne()
      @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
      public Role getRole() {}
}
```

Would the correct way to model this relationship be as above, or would I drop the private Long roleId; in Users? Any advice welcomed.
When I map it this way, I receive the following error:

```
 org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
```

Comment: Do you really want to limit your users to having exactly one (or none) `Role`?

Comment: @Role. In this app, yes, they should have only 1 role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would drop the `private Long roleId` mapping when you have a `@ManyToOne` on the same column.

As the error implies, you can only map each column in an @Entity once.  Since `role_id` is the `@JoinColumn` for the `@ManyToOne` reference, you cannot also map it as a property.

You can, however, add a convenience method to return the role ID, like

```
 public Long getRoleId() {
   return role.getId();
 }
```

Comment: also - not integral to the question but you probably don't need `@Access` modifier by default

Comment: thanks. When I drop the private Long roleId, everything seems to work well. I just didn't know if I should since it was in the backend database table. But I guess it is acceptable to do so.